# Regarding implementing swipe in android application

Tags: android

I am developing an android application game in which I have to implement swipe. User swipes from left to right and then he selects particular image which is shown. I have tried googling it, but couldn't find something useful that has helped me,

The image is

http://www.imagehousing.com/image/839095

If anyone has implemented it before,
can he guide me

Thanks in advance
Tushar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a nice sample example for you.

[Example of Gallery 1](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-gallery-example)

[Example of Gallery 2](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2010/05/gallery-view-android-developer-tutorial.html)

Comment: this is actually a swipe,we swipe from left to right,the link u have provided is different.....

Comment: i want the image swiping from left to right,,,,is it possible using gallery?

Comment: Well, a simple gallery provides that functionality inbuilt.

Comment: sahni it a good example,,but how to swipe that streched image,,, have u seen my image that i hosted on url?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're after the [gallery](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html)? It looks like it should do exactly what you want. The gallery handles all this functionality for you.

You can handle any onClick functionality like so, using `setOnItemClickListener`:

```
    mGallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
    });
```

Comment: its a swipe,,and gallery contains grid of images

Comment: So does your example image you provided. o-O - Based on your image/spec this is what you want, you swipe left and right to go through the images which is exactly that the gallery does. Otherwise, you need to make your question clearer.

Comment: The gallery is what you need then! It swipes left and right, the functionality is built in already.

Comment: ,,,,, is it possible in gallery to scroll left to right in horizontal scroll view

Comment: Yes. Click the link I provided and give it a go, I think it'll fit your needs.

Comment: if possible can u implement demo of this image?

Comment: I haven't got the time, but you have 3 examples to work with. It's time to get coding ;)